# Installing wordpress to run on xampp Lion OS X

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I am having some trouble installing wordpress on my mac. It is the first time I have ever used xampp and I have been following the guides but seem to have gone wrong and cannot find a solution through google. I downloaded xampp, installed it, enabled apache, mysql but not ftp... I get the error:

```
 - error: no valid servers configured
 - Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

I tried just carrying on as I wasn't sure if this was an issue. I downloaded wordpress copied it into the htdocs in the xampp directory, renamed the config file from the example name and got the unique keys and salts from the api url then replacing the keys in the config.

I then was told to go to localhost where i should have a directory view of the htpdocs folder.  Ijust get the xampp homescreen.... hope someone can help me!?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Wordpress then you can try using [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com) for Mac, you can install Wordpress very easily on a single click and also get immediate updates, it also provides 230+ scripts with it. I started using AMPPS for my Mac 10.7.1 some days back and I didn't faced any problem till now as it has a very friendly GUI. You can just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need FTP while working locally. So I wouldn't worry too much about the error there.

Once you have xampp homescreen, that means that you're set up - any websites / applications you write should go inside httpdocs/ folder; so you end up with

httpdocs/.
httpdocs/Wordpress

If you go to http://localhost/Wordpress/ you should see the Wordpress installation screen.

That should be enough to get you started :)